# How many ways are there for a bank to choose n students?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

A bank comes to campus and interviews each person one at a time. After each interview they decide to hire that person or not.

i. There are n students. How many decisions does the bank make?

ii. How many ways are there to choose students to get jobs at the bank?

I am confused about this. I think on the first one that maybe we let k be the number of decisions the bank makes. Since there are n students and the bank makes k decisions, we have $\binom{n}{k}$. And isn't the second one identical to the first one? Or maybe it's just $2^{n}$ ways to choose students to offer jobs at the bank?

Comment: You think too complicatedly. They make a decision for every student they interview. They do $n$ interviews. So they make $n$ decisions.

Comment: I just realized what happened. For i, the bank can either accept or reject a student after the interview so they have $2^{n}$ decisions 
for ii, the student can decision whether or not to accept or decline the bank's job offer, so it's also $2^{n}$ decisions.

Comment: typos... I meant for ii, the student can decide whether or not to accept or decline the bank's job offer so it's $2^{n}$ decisions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that this is overthinking it a bit.

i. There are n students, and each student is a yes or no, leaving n decisions

ii. Every student has 2 options (yes or no), leaving $2^n$

Comment: Or $\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk = (1+1)^n = 2^n$.

Comment: I got so confused because it is just asking How many decisions... oh wait I think for both it's just $2^{n}$ because the bank can make a yes or no decision and the student can either make a yes or no decision as well.